# Optional class members without runtime overhead

Tags: c++

I have the following very general problem that I have not found a satisfying solution to yet:
So I want to have two classes `A` and `AData` that are basically identical except that the latter has an additional attribute `data` and each of the classes supports a function `foo()`, which is different because it depends on the existence of the additional data.

The stupid solution is to copy the entire class and change it slightly, but that leads to code duplication and is hard to maintain. Using std::optional or a pointer lead to additional checks and therefore runtime overhead, right?

My question is whether there is a way to get the same runtime performance as just copying the code without actual code duplication? My current solution is to make `AData` a derived class and declare it as friend of `A` and then override the virtual function `foo()`, but I do not like this approach due to the use of `friend`.

Comment: Why do you need to declare it as a friend? The  point of inheritance is to solve the "problem" you mentioned or am I missing something? Maybe you could put it in a small code sample that we (or only I) can understand it better

Comment: Any reason you don't have `AData` derive from `A`?

Comment: Because the function ```foo()``` needs access to private members in both cases. I should probably clarify that.

Comment: And you cannot make the private members protected?

Comment: BTW: using std::optional or std::variant may have the same overhead as a call over vtable has. It is hardly depending on the optimization of the compiler. For me it is quite unclear what the real use case is! Use a derived class and a virtual method is quite fine, no "friend" is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use static polymorphism and curiosly recurring template pattern.
Both `A` and `AData` provide `foo()` but behaviour is class-specfic through `doFoo()`. Also not using virtual dispatch avoids runtime overhead of vtable lookup.

```
template <typename TData>
class Abase
{
public:
   void foo()
   {
       static_cast<TData*>(this)->doFoo();
   }
};

class A : public Abase<A>
{
    friend ABase<A>;
    void doFoo() { cout << "A::foo()\n"; }
};

class AData : public Abase<AData>
{
   friend Abase<AData>;
   int someDataMember;
   void doFoo() {  cout << "AData::foo()\n"; /*... use someDataMember ... */}
};
```

[Live](https://ideone.com/U2D3tI)

Comment: "Also not using virtual dispatch improves performance." But the dispatch must be done somewhere. if it uses std::variant it takes also time. Manual dispatch with if/else also. Typically vtable dispatch is quite fast and std::variant can be the same but not faster.

Comment: @Klaus: the dispatch here is done at compile time, so no runtime overhead. vtable lookup is performed at runtime.

Comment: I agree with Klaus. Either we know the concrete type and no virtual dispatch will be needed, or we don't and we have just moved that dispatch to be managed outside of the class.

Comment: You have no dispatch here. The need comes up if you store elements of both types and want to call the function of the obejct. At this point dispatch must happen.

Comment: The "dispatch" here is that compiler will just invoke the right call at template instantiation. One could also inline calls. In any case there is no runtime dispatch through vtable. And yeah, if one really wants to treat both times polymorphicaly at runtime, as accessing derived class through base class pointer, then virtual behaviour would be needed

Comment: Can you fix the doFoo call so it compiles, or should I?

Comment: Is there a good solution to make doFoo() private?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use composition:

```
class A
{
public:
    void foo() { /*...*/ }
};

class AData
{
   A a;
   int someDataMember;
public:
    void foo() { /*... use someDataMember ...*/ }
};
```

Comment: +1: Without any further details by the OP about the conrete usage scenario, composition should be the better design approach here in doubt, besides maybe a private inheritance.

Comment: I think that behaves quite differently than a copied class because a function in ```A``` that uses ```foo()``` will not be replaced or can you somehow make that work? Maybe I should have been more precise what the requirements are.